# How to edit the subtotal on invoice

Tags: magento

I want to add the custom tax on magento invoice pdf ,that is 10% of subtotal.
how to get the subtotal value in variable and print it on invoice pdf.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In file /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/abstract.php. edit the following function line number 577.

```
  protected function insertTotals($page, $source){
        $order = $source->getOrder();
        $totals = $this->_getTotalsList($source);
        $lineBlock = array(
            'lines'  => array(),
            'height' => 15
        );
        $i = 1 ;

        foreach ($totals as $total) {
            $total->setOrder($order)
                ->setSource($source);

            if ($total->canDisplay()) {
                $total->setFontSize(10);
                foreach ($total->getTotalsForDisplay() as $totalData) {
                       $j = $i+1 ;                  




       $lineBlock['lines'][] = array(

                        array(
                            'text'      => $totalData['label'],
                            'feed'      => 475,
                            'align'     => 'right',
                            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
                            'font'      => 'bold'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'text'      => $totalData['amount'],
                            'feed'      => 565,
                            'align'     => 'right',
                            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
                            'font'      => 'bold'
                        ),
                    );


                    if($totalData['label']=='Subtotal:'){
                 $abc =  preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $totalData['amount']);              
                $getval = str_replace(array(','), '' , $abc);
                $getsubval = ($getval*10)/100;
                $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($getsubval, true, false);




                        if($j==2){

                    $lineBlock['lines'][] = array(
                        array(
                            'text'      => '10% Tax Added',
                            'feed'      => 475,
                            'align'     => 'right',
                            'font_size' => $totalData['font_size'],
                            'font'      => 'bold'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'text'      => $formattedPrice,
                            'feed'      => 565,
                            'align'     => 'right',
                            'font_size' => '',
                            'font'      => 'bold'
                        ),
                    );  
                    }


                    }

                }
            }
        }

        $this->y -= 20;
        $page = $this->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock));
        return $page;
    }

    /**
     * Parse item description
     *
     * @param  Varien_Object $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _parseItemDescription($item)
    {
        $matches = array();
        $description = $item->getDescription();
        if (preg_match_all('/<li.*?>(.*?)<\/li>/i', $description, $matches)) {
            return $matches[1];
        }

        return array($description);
    }

    /**
     * Before getPdf processing
     */
    protected function _beforeGetPdf() {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');

        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
    }
```